# Setting initial value in Kendo Drop Down

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

How to set value of the kendo UI drop down server side, depending on what data is sent by client?

Comment: What do you mean to set value on server side? The dropdown is a client-side component and it is generally the server that send data to it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [value](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#value%20stringdefault) setting to set the initially selected value.

Comment: value takes a string but the field its bound to is an int. How do you do it then?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
       if ($(this).parent().hasClass("k-widget k-dropdown k-header")) {

                    var combo = $(this).data("kendoDropDownList");
                    combo.select(4); // set the value to this index item
                    break;
                }
```